# How to make CSS flex properties compatible with older browsers?

Tags: android, html, css, flexbox

I need to create a passcode screen where I can display digits like below

[image: Passcode image]

I am able to create it using "Display: Flex" CSS property, But it is not compatible with older browsers (Like Android 4.2.2 browser).

How can I make it compatible?

```
<div class="ILS_lock">
<div class="ILS_numbers-row">
  <div class="ILS_digit">1</div>
  <div class="ILS_digit">2</div>
  <div class="ILS_digit">3</div>
</div>
```

```
          .ILS_lock {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 999;
        background-color: {{backgroundColor}};
      }
      .ILS_lock-hidden {
        display: none;
      }
      .ILS_label-row {
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 23px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        color: {{textColor}};
      }
      .ILS_circles-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
      }
      .ILS_circle {
        background-color: {{backgroundColor}}!important;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border:solid 1px {{textColor}};
        margin: 0 15px;
      }
      .ILS_numbers-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
      }
      .ILS_digit {
        margin: 0 14px;
        width: 80px;
        border-radius: 10%;
        height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 29px;
        font-size: 21px;
        color: {{buttonTextColor}};
        background-color: {{buttonColor}};
      }
```

JsFiddle link -> https://jsfiddle.net/sandeshbsuvarna/0nxrbckm/2/

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Can you help me on the JSFiddle Link I have provided?

Comment: Post your CSS in [**autoprefixer**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). It will add the prefixes you need for older browsers. Read my answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276) to know more about browser compatibility, and also see [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Comment: @Michael_B Saviour. It worked like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to make the CSS compatible. Worked like charm.

Below code is compatible with < Android 4.2.2 Browsers

> ```
>       .ILS_lock {
>         display: -webkit-box;
>         display: -ms-flexbox;
>         display: flex;
>         -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
>         -webkit-box-direction: normal;
>             -ms-flex-direction: column;
>                 flex-direction: column;
>         -webkit-box-pack: center;
>             -ms-flex-pack: center;
>                 justify-content: center;
>         position: absolute;
>         width: 100%;
>         height: 100%;
>         z-index: 999;
>       }
>       .ILS_lock-hidden {
>         display: none;
>       }
>       .ILS_label-row {
>         height: 50px;
>         width: 100%;
>         text-align: center;
>         font-size: 23px;
>         padding-top: 10px;
>       }
>       .ILS_circles-row {
>         display: -webkit-box;
>         display: -ms-flexbox;
>         display: flex;
>         -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
>         -webkit-box-direction: normal;
>             -ms-flex-direction: row;
>                 flex-direction: row;
>         -webkit-box-pack: center;
>             -ms-flex-pack: center;
>                 justify-content: center;
>         width: 100%;
>         height: 60px;
>       }
>       .ILS_circle {
>         border-radius: 50%;
>         width: 10px;
>         height: 10px;
>         margin: 0 15px;
>       }
>       .ILS_numbers-row {
>         display: -webkit-box;
>         display: -ms-flexbox;
>         display: flex;
>         -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
>         -webkit-box-direction: normal;
>             -ms-flex-direction: row;
>                 flex-direction: row;
>         -webkit-box-pack: center;
>             -ms-flex-pack: center;
>                 justify-content: center;
>         width: 100%;
>         height: 100px;
>       }
>       .ILS_digit {
>         margin: 0 14px;
>         width: 80px;
>         border-radius: 10%;
>         height: 80px;
>         text-align: center;
>         padding-top: 29px;
>         font-size: 21px;
>       }
> ```